# Have separate legends for a set of point-line plots, and a vertical line plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Example data frame (if there's a better/more idiomatic way to do this, let me know):

```
n <- 10  
group <- rep(c("A","B","C"),each = n)
x   <- rep(seq(0,1,length = n),3)
y   <- ifelse(group == "A",1+x,ifelse(group == "B",2+2*x,3+3*x))
df  <- data.frame(group,x,y)
xd  <- 0.5
des <- data.frame(xd)
```

I want to plot create point-line plots for the data in `df`, add a vertical curve at the `x` location indicated by `xd`, and get readable legends for both. I tried the following:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(linetype=group))
p <- p + geom_vline(data = des, aes(xintercept = xd), color = "blue")
p
```

[image]
Not quite what I had in mind, there's no legend for the vertical line.

A small modification (I don't understand why `geom_vline` is one of the few geometries with a `show.legend` parameter, which moreover defaults to `FALSE`!):

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(linetype=group))
p <- p + geom_vline(data = des, aes(xintercept = xd), color = "blue", show.legend = TRUE)
p
```

[image]

At least now the vertical bar is showing in the legend, but I don't want it to go in the same "category" (?) as `group`. I would like another legend entry, titled `Design`, and containing only the vertical line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach is to add an extra dummy aesthetic like `fill =`, which we'll subsequently use to create the second legend in combination with `scale_fill_manual()` :

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        geom_line(aes(linetype=group), show.legend = TRUE) + 
        geom_vline(data = des, 
                   aes(xintercept = xd, fill = "Vertical Line"), # add dummy fill
                   colour = "blue") +
        scale_fill_manual(values = 1, "Design", # customize second legend 
                guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("blue"))))
```

[image]

Comment: I would give you +2 for the **fantastic** Rick avatar, but alas, I can only give you +1 for the nice answer :)

Comment: I get the need for  `override.aes` in `scale_fill_manual`, but why did you have to move `show.legend = TRUE` in the `geom_line` geometry? It's correct, because otherwise the solution doesn't work, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You can put it inside the `geom_vline()` as well, but that messes up the way the legends are displayed for some reason . It seems to be a known, yet not fully resolved issue, see here: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1267